# error message for rmarkdown on MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: r, runtime-error, r-markdown, macos-sierra

Could someone help me resolve this error message I am getting when I try to create an rmarkdown file in my Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6? I tried running this uninstall from the terminal...

sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
Then downloaded Command line tools 11.3.1 from developer.apple.com
That didn't work.

Thank you for your help!

```
Installing 'rmarkdown' for R Markdown...
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rmarkdown_2.11.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3212367 bytes (3.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.1 MB

Warning in file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file '/var/db/timezone/zoneinfo/+VERSION': No such file or directory
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libR.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libR.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/INSTALL: line 34:  2932 Done                    echo 'tools:::.install_packages()'
      2933 Abort trap: 6           | R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES= LC_COLLATE=C "${R_HOME}/bin/R" $myArgs --no-echo --args ${args}

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/3b/3pqm57xd07s13kw1m856pt2m0000gn/T/Rtmp3J83YY/downloaded_packages’


✔ Package 'rmarkdown' successfully installed.
Warning message:
In utils::install.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/",  :
  installation of package ‘rmarkdown’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: I see warning messages, not error messages. The difference probably seems pedantic, but one means what you were trying to do worked (possibly with caveats) and the other means it didn't. Did the packages you wanted install successfully?

Comment: Try [`xcode-select --install`](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1133#issuecomment-331498031) in terminal (or however they call this on mac).

Comment: It appears that you are trying to build `rmarkdown` from its sources, rather than using the build already provided by CRAN. If you don't need to build from sources, then you don't need Command Line Tools at all. You can download and install the CRAN build by running `install.packages("rmarkdown")` at your R prompt.

Comment: The reason for the warning is that you have installed on macOS 10.12 a build of R intended for macOS 10.13 and higher (that is stated in your output and also [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/)). If you want to safely use R 4.1.x, then you need to update to macOS 10.13 or higher (or build R yourself, but that's hard).